# Issue with Z-index: Button with Position Relative Appears Above Absolute Positioned Notification Menu, but Moves Below When position: relative Removed

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass

I'm currently facing an issue with the z-index property in my web application. I have a notification menu that is set to position: absolute and z-index: 1000. When the menu is open, it should overlay other elements on the page. However, I'm encountering a problem where a button with position: relative (and no explicit z-index set) is appearing above the notification menu.

Menu Code

```
    <div class="dropdown-list dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in"
                    aria-labelledby="alertsDropdown"> 
                    \\ postion absolute & z index 1000
                    <h6 class="dropdown-header">
                        Alerts Center
                    </h6>
                    <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                        <div class="mr-3">
                            <div class="icon-circle bg-primary">
                                <i class="fas fa-file-alt text-white"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="small text-gray-500">December 12, 2019</div>
                            <span class="font-weight-bold">A new monthly report is ready to download!</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>    
                    <a class="dropdown-item text-center small text-gray-500" href="#">Show All Alerts</a>
   </div>
```

Button Code

```
<div class="dropdown-menu animated--fade-in"
           aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
           // position relative & no z-index
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
       </div>
```

Despite the z-index of the notification menu being set to a high value (1000), the button still shows above it when the menu is open. Surprisingly, when I remove position: relative from the button, the button moves below the notification menu, as expected.

What could be causing this unexpected behavior, and how can I ensure that the notification menu appears above other elements, including this button, when it's open? Additionally, why does the button move below the menu when the position: relative is removed?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)